# evaluate condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 tables: Course, Professor, Degree.

The course table lists all courses being taught and the professor who is assigned to teach it using the professor ID.
The professor table lists all the professors along with their general contact information.  It’s primary key is the professor ID.
The degree table lists all the degrees held by professors using their professor ID as a foreign key.

The problem I am having is that when I want a listing of each course along with the assigned professor and whether that professor has a doctorate degree.  If they do return a “Y” if not return an “N”.   I only want one result per professor despite there being multiple entries for each professor in the table.

[Sample Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iepfn.png)

```
ProfessorID Professor
01          Mary Smith
02          Harry Johnson
03          Teddy Fitz
04          Larry Manson
05          Sarah Love


CourseID    CourseName   ProfessorID
001         Math 101     01
002         English 201  01
003         English101   02
004         Math 101     03
005         Science 101  04
```

[Sample Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAcek.png)

```
DegreeID    Degree  Doctorate Degree    ProfessorID
0001        BA      N                   01
0002        MS      N                   01
0003        PHD     Y                   01
0004        BA      N                   02
0005        MS      N                   02
0006        BA      N                   03
0007        MS      N                   03
0008        EDD     Y                   03
0009        BA      N                   04
```

The Results I would like is:

```
Course       Professor      Doctorate
Math 101     Mary Smith     Y
English 201  Mary Smith     Y
English101   Harry Johnson  N
Math 101     Teddy Fitz     Y
Science 101  Larry Manson   N
```

However, I keep getting a result for each degree that the professor has; regardless of whether it is a doctorate or not.  Such as the following:

```
Course      Professor       Doctorate
Math 101    Mary Smith      Y
Math 101    Mary Smith      N
English 201 Mary Smith      Y
English 201 Mary Smith      N
English101  Harry Johnson   N
Math 101    Teddy Fitz      Y
Science 101 Larry Manson    N
```

How should I code this?

Comment: Please show us your tried.

Comment: We can't tell you why your statement isn't working, because you didn't show us the SQL statement you've tried. Please [edit] to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to achieve what you want. I'll site 2 examples:

You can use `LEFT JOIN` + `COALESCE`, since those professor without doctorate can be default to 'N':

```
SELECT 
A.CourseName,
B.Professor,
COALESCE(C.Doctorate, 'N')
FROM course_table as A
LEFT JOIN professor_table as B
ON A.ProfessorID = B.ProfessorID
LEFT JOIN degree_table as C
ON B.ProfessorID = C.ProfessorID AND C.Doctorate = 'Y'
```

UPDATED:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding.  The first query worked great except one thing.  Professors who do not have a doctorate are completely eliminated from the results.  I still need for those professors to be included in the result set.  I just need it to say "N" in their doctorate field.

Comment: @May can you re-try the 2nd query? I'll try to recheck my first query.

Comment: Hi, I re-tried the 2nd query again and the problem is that the max(degreeID) is not always the Doctorate degree.  Sometimes the data entry specialists don't put the Doctorate degree in last. For example a new professor may have all three degrees and as they input them into the system they may input the doctorate first and then the BA and then the MS. My first thought was the same and used the entry time stamp to determine what degree they had and realized it was out of order

Comment: updated my answer and tried it in SQLize and its working fine

Comment: @May use both left join for the query. check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of fixing it. Given the final result table, you can use a statement similar to the following to get the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT Course, Professor, MAX(Doctorate) as Doctorate 
FROM YOUR_RESULTING_TABLE 
GROUP BY Course, Professor
```

the MAX() function on letters return based on the lexicographic(alphabetical) order.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for responding! The only problem with this statement is that sometimes when a new professor comes in the data entry specialists don't always put the Doctorate degree in last.  For example a new person may have all three degrees and as they input them into the system they may input the doctorate first and then the BA and then the MS.  My first thought was the same and used the entry time stamp to determine what degree they had and realized it was out of order.

Comment: This is not based on the order when the data is entered! The MAX function here operates on column Doctorate which take values "Y" and "N"; the letter "Y" appears higher in order compared to "N" therefore the MAX function returns the row with value "Y" if there is multiple rows with the same Course, Professor but different values for Doctorate(for example, Math 101,Mary Smith rows)!